# Typo3 - Folder "/" does not exist - Error

Tags: typo3, uncaught-exception, typo3-8.7.x

I have a problem in Typo3. When I am in the backend in the filelist menu or want to link something, I get the error message: "#1314516810: Folder "/" does not exist." (see screenshot).

[image]

[image: fileadmin settings]

The folder exists of course, and everything worked until recently, the error suddenly appeared from one day to the next. I have already googled the error and searched several forums, but I cannot find a solution to my problem.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is and how I can fix it? Thank you very much in advance.

Typo3-Version 8.7.32
Webserver: Apache
PHP-Version: 7.4.28
Database: MariaDB 10.3.34
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Server Management via Plesk Obsidian 18.0.43

Regards

Comment: Please check path of your file storage, if it is still correct. Switch from absPath to relPath.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I'm new to typo3, can I check the path in the typo3 backend or do I have to look in a specific config file on the server? If so, could you tell me in which file I have to look?

Comment: List module -> Select Root page on top with UID 0 -> scroll to table with file storages -> open/edit file storage with name "fileadmin" -> Check, if path is valid

Comment: I checked the settings and everything seems fine. I included another screenshot of the fileadmin settings.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the folder permissions? It should be `755` or maybe `775` and your webserver user should be the owner. Or in case of `775` the webserver user should be in the usergroup that has access rights to this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the extension fal_securedownload?

If yes, and you are using a subfolder name under fileadmin with more than 30 characters, shorten this subfolder name, like stated here:

https://github.com/beechit/fal_securedownload/issues/137